# Django nested serializer not serializing inner model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im trying to add a custom `action` to my `ViewSet` in Django2, using `django-rest-framework`. Problem is that my serializer is not serializing nested model and thus giving me error:

```
{
    "labels": [
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Label."
            ]
        },
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Label."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have two models which have M:N relationship.

Label model:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Name of Label')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Description of Label')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

LabelSet model:

```
class LabelSet(models.Model):
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label, blank=True, help_text='ManyToMany field of corresponding labels')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Name of Label Set')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Description of Label Set')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Machine Model:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Name of machine')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Description of machine')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='ID of machine location')
    labelset = models.ForeignKey(LabelSet, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, help_text='ID of set of labels relevant for this machine')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = '__all__'

class LabelSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    qs = Label.objects.all().values()
    labels = LabelSerializer(qs, many=True)
    class Meta:
        depth = 1
        model = LabelSet
        fields = ('name', 'desc', 'labels')
```

Custom action in `viewsets.py` (I want to retrieve available labels by machine, so path is `/machines/{id}/labels`

```
class MachineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    A viewset used for retrieving and editing Machine instances.
    '''
    #permission_classes = (DRYPermissions,)
    serializer_class = MachineSerializer
    queryset = Machine.objects.all()

    # /api/v1/machines/{machine_id}/labels
    @action(detail=True)
    def labels(self, request, pk=None):
        # Get labelset id
        ls = Machine.objects.get(pk=pk).labelset

        # Get LabelSet instance
        serializer = LabelSetSerializer(data=model_to_dict(ls))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The endpoint works fine, but when querying `/machines/1/labels` i got the response which is the first snippet:

> "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Label."

Im literally out of ideas, tried even making dict from `qs = Label.objects.all().values()` in `Serializer`, no luck.

Thanks to @Jerin Peter George, output is now:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "TestSet",
    "desc": "asd",
    "labels": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "OK",
            "desc": "desc"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Broken",
            "desc": "asd"
        }
    ]
}
```

So `/api/v1/machines/1/labels` works, but suddenly `/api/v1/machines/` does not. (`502 Bad Gateway with error TypeError: 'LabelSet' object is not iterable`)

APP level urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from devices.viewsets import *
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', DeviceViewSet, base_name='device')
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet, base_name='project')
router.register(r'locations', LocationViewSet, base_name='location')
router.register(r'industries', IndustryViewSet, base_name='industry')
router.register(r'companies', CompanyViewSet, base_name='companies')
router.register(r'project_types', ProjectTypeViewSet, base_name='project_type')
router.register(r'device_types', DeviceTypeViewSet, base_name='device_type')
router.register(r'machines', MachineViewSet, base_name='machine')
router.register(r'records', RecordViewSet, base_name='record')
router.register(r'labels', LabelViewSet, base_name='label')
router.register(r'labelsets', LabelSetViewSet, base_name='label_set')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

App level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
from rest_framework_expiring_authtoken import views
from devices.views import AudioUploadView

API_PREFIX = 'api/v1/'

urlpatterns = [
    url(API_PREFIX + 'docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Docs')),
    url(API_PREFIX + 'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(API_PREFIX + 'api-token-auth/', views.obtain_expiring_auth_token),
    path(API_PREFIX, include('devices.urls'))
]
```

EDIT: SOLVED
Apparently i added one more nested serializer to `MachineSerializer`

```
class MachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    labelsets = LabelSetSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:            
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'
```

So removing the line `labelsets = LabelSetSerializer(many=True)` did the trick.
And that is where the error came from, now is everything working as expected, thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `labels()` with below snippet,

```
@action(detail=True)
def labels(self, request, pk=None):
    # Get labelset id
    ls = Machine.objects.get(pk=pk).labelset

    # Get LabelSet instance
    serializer = LabelSetSerializer(ls)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input! Give me a minute so I can try this :)

Comment: No idea what made the difference, but it is now working, thank you :)

Comment: Actually, it should be like that~

Comment: Well, it is working, but now my whole /machines/ endpoint is giving 502 Bad Gateway with error `TypeError: 'LabelSet' object is not iterable
` :(

Comment: can you add `urls.py`  in `question` section?

Comment: Sure, done. But im not exposing this action manually, DRF router and viewsets are taking care of this.

Comment: also add `MachineSerializer` class

Comment: Check my edited question, it was really in `MachineSerializer` class, thank you very much.